# jQuery pull text from selected facet

Tags: jquery, drupal, title, dropdownbox

i have a facet dropdown that i have attached a class to parent div and am trying to use that to pull the selected item out and display in the h2 title of the drop down.

here is what i have

```
 jQuery(select, 'a').filter(function(){
           return jQuery(this).has('.facetapi-active').length > 0
       }).each(function(){
           jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
       });
```

this add the class to the parent of the active or selected item and this

```
 if (jQuery(select).hasClass('selected')){
        //alert('almost there')
          jQuery('.selected').find('h2').text('display')
      }
```

gets the title or h2 to read display if the class is selected but i need it for each drop down and display it for that drop only. this variable  has the text but it displays same text in each h2.

`var selection = jQuery('.selected .facetapi-processed').find('li').text();`

How do i make specific for each i already tried jQuery(this) and got nothing?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the HTML? It's a little difficult to understand the context.

Comment: i unfortunately was unable to to find a way to do this. if anyone else has any ideas i would still like to see what you came up with.           @RyanHenderson this was inside of a Drupal 7 installation there was no way for me to get the html to print out here. thanks for the help thou.